# setout file is not getting generated daily based on date

Tags: java, server, server-side, serversocket, tcp

I have application which keeps listening on a port and if any request comes ,processes and sends the response back.I have redirected System.out.println of the program to a text file. I want the file to be rolledout everyday.But i don see a rollout at 12.00 am .Sometimes rollout happens and sometimes logs are appended on yesterday's file itself. Code snippet given below.

```
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintStream;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;

 public class MBServ {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean listening = true;
    String request_date = null;
    String request_time = null;
    String logFile="MBServ_";
    ConnectServiceInfo fiServiceInfo = ConnectServiceInfo.getInstance();
    ConnectServiceInfo fiservice = fiServiceInfo.getInstance();
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1122);


    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.exit(-1);

    }

    while (listening) {

        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        request_date = sdf.format(date);
        logFile="MBServ_"+request_date+".log";
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(logFile,true)));

        new MBServT(serverSocket.accept(), fiservice).start();
        }

    serverSocket.close();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or exceptions ?

Comment: no error/exception.But logs are getting appended to old files instead of creating new file when the date changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to force the creation of the file before using it.

**Here's an exmaple :**

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
request_date = sdf.format(date);
logFile="MBServ_"+request_date+".log";
File file = new File(logFile);
file.createNewFile();
...
```

Documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

Comment: I made the changes as per above code snippet.Still it does not create new file when date changes

Comment: it creates new file but not exactly at 00.01 AM.It creates at different time every day